# Can I "mute" all f-curve drivers in a single click?

Tags: rigging, drivers

I often need to review the results of my face-rig's expression animation transitions. However while drivers are connected to the bones the animation data does not change the bone's transform when the playhead is scrubbed.

Instead I must manually either delete all drivers, or mute them one-by-one:

Is there a way to mute all drivers at once?

[image]

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9Z2QDzdVEM) which shows exactly my main issue (notice how bone animation is only seen when drivers are removed or muted)

[EDIT]

This is possible to do with Python. So now I can make a custom menu button for this in the future.

```
for driver in bpy.context.object.animation_data.drivers:
    driver.mute = True
```

[UPDATE]

And here's the custom menu button script so this can all done with a single click:

```
import bpy

class CustomDriverControls(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_DRIVER_CONTROLS"
    bl_label = "Custom Driver Controls"
    bl_space_type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.operator("my.button", text="Mute Drivers").number=1
        row.operator("my.button", text="Un-Mute Drivers").number=2

class OBJECT_OT_Button(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.button"
    bl_label = "Button"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    number = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    row = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    loc = bpy.props.StringProperty()
 
    def execute(self, context):
        if self.number is 1 or self.number is 2:
            for driver in bpy.context.object.animation_data.drivers:
                driver.mute = self.number is 1
        return{'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__" :  
    register()
```

Simply copy the above code into the texteditor of your project and press run. Then navigate to the driver panel and you should see two new buttons for muting and un-muting all driver.
[image]
It would still be very nice to find a more standard (portable) way to do this.

[UPDATE]

So I was just made aware that all of the above is not nescessary and Blender does in fact have a built in way to handle setting all selected to "mute"

> Quote by Rich Sedman [found here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95437/32655)
>
> "If you select
> multiple channels you can then use the Toggle Channel Setting (in the
> Channel menu or Shift-W) to toggle all the selected channel's 'Mute'
> setting at once"

Comment: With options in a list, like graph editor, dopesheet and outliner, you can also drag over multiple items.