# How to quickly preview what a shape key with a driver does?

Tags: interface, shape-keys

I have a shape key with a driver. Its value is currently 0. I'd like to "preview" what it does (a.k.a. see its shape at value 1), but because its value is controlled by the driver, I have to `RMB` > `Edit Driver`, find the driver, and change its value, or remove the driver first then add it back later.

Both seem very tedious for such a simple task. Is there a faster way to "preview" a shape key?

Comment: You can select the object and go into edit mode (Tab button). From there select you shape key and you should instantly see the value at 1.0. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I would just save the project, remove the driver(s), preview, **revert**.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95352/how-do-i-temporaily-turn-off-a-driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Pin icon under Shape keys ...

[image]

[image]

Edit: ... I dont know much about drivers, but you can duplicate (copy&paste) driver of each shape key and use like one Empty_Master object that will control Value for all your shape keys at once ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not exactly as setting value as 1 (if you have more than one shape keys). But yeah I guess it's good enough

Comment: You didnt mention ... Edit ... if that make a sence to you :)